# Const array initialization from other const arrays

Tags: c, arrays, c-preprocessor

A code snippet like the following:

```
static const double foo[3] = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 };
static const double bar[3] = { foo[0]*foo[0], 3*foo[1], foo[2]+4.0 };
```

generates a compiler error stating that the initialization values are not constants.

There are some arrays of data (can assume a fixed size) and several other ones, dependent and related to them in fairly simple ways, that would be useful to precompute at compile-time rather than run-time. But since the source data may need to be changed, I would prefer that such changes avoid manually re-computing the dependent arrays.

I suppose one could make some utility that generates a .h file, but at this point I'm curious--is there a way to do something like this (enter the data for a const array only once, but have several other const arrays be dependent on them) in the C preprocessor that's cleaner than (say) defining a preprocessor macro for each and every element of each source array?

P.S. If there's some preprocessor library that could do something like this, I would really appreciate a code example.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your original array is actually a list of special constants, and `foo` is just a collection of them all.

You can achieve something similar using defines and constructing the arrays from those for use in the program later:

```
#define SpecialA 1.0
#define SpecialB 2.0
#define SpecialC 3.0

static const double foo[3] = { SpecialA, SpecialB, SpecialC };
static const double bar[3] = { SpecialA*SpecialA, 3*SpecialB, SpecialC+4.0 };
```

Comment: It is so, but since there's going to be a metric crapload of them in the end, I was curious about a way to do it that's cleaner than crafting individual preprocessor macros for each one. Still, if there isn't, I'll probably end up doing something like this.

Comment: how is the metric crapload being generated?  Perhaps it should be generated in #define form instead of as an array?

Answer (score 1):

After fiddling with the preprocessor some, it turned out to be easier than I thought it would be. The objective was to enter the data for the source array only once while avoiding definitions for every entry individually. This is possible by defining the contents of the array as a preprocessor macro:

```
#define FOO      1.0, 2.0, 3.0
static const double foo[] = { FOO };
static const double bar[] = { ARR_EL(0,FOO)*ARR_EL(0,FOO), \
                              3.0*ARR_EL(1,FOO), ARR_EL(2,FOO)+4.0 };
/* Whatever else */
```

where the helper macros are as follows:

```
/* ARR_EL(n,...) returns nth element of the array */
#define ARR_EL(n,...)      ARR_EL0(ARR_BEGIN(n,__VA_ARGS__))
#define ARR_EL0(...)       ARR_ELX(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ARR_ELX(e0,...)    (e0)

/* ARR_BEGIN(n,...) returns subarray starting with nth element */
#define ARR_BEGIN(n,...)   ARR_BEGIN##n(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ARR_BEGIN0(...)    __VA_ARGS__ /* Why is this even here? */
#define ARR_BEGIN1(...)    ARR_BEGINX(__VA_ARGS__)
#define ARR_BEGINX(e0,...) __VA_ARGS__
#define ARR_BEGIN2(...)    ARR_BEGIN1(ARR_BEGIN1(__VA_ARGS__))
#define ARR_BEGIN3(...)    ARR_BEGIN2(ARR_BEGIN1(__VA_ARGS__))
#define ARR_BEGIN4(...)    ARR_BEGIN3(ARR_BEGIN1(__VA_ARGS__))
/* Extendible in the obvious way */
```

Tested in gcc (cpp 4.1.1) and tcc, but I believe this should all be standard C99.

Without the extra step provided by the `ARR_ELX` and `ARR_BEGINX` macros, the preprocessor sometimes treats `FOO` as a single argument.